# Google App Engine getting verbose_name of a property from an instance

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Given a model like so:

```
 from google.appengine.ext import db
 class X(db.Model):
    p = db.StringProperty(verbose_name="Like π, but more modern.")
```

How does one access verbose_name from `x=X()` (an instance of `X`)?

One might expect that `x.p.verbose_name` would work, or alternatively `x.properties()['p'].verbose_name`, but neither seems to work.

Thanks!

EDIT: x.*name*.verbose_name => x.p.verbose_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.properties()['p'].verbose_name` definitely works - you can verify for yourself on http://shell.appspot.com/

Comment: Okay, thank you. Strange - it just didn't seem to work when I was trying it. Must've been a bug in my code! At least I had the right idea. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = X(p="Foo!")
print x.p.verbose_name
```

Does that work?

Comment: Alas, no. (Fixed typo in the example). Note that I'm trying to access `x.p.verbose_name` in Jinja2, if that makes any difference.